# How long should an exposé be usually?

Tags: research-proposal, humanities

There is this position advertised and among its requirements is an exposé of the research the applicant wants to undertake during the fellowship. But it doesn't say anything about the size of the exposé. Is there a usual size for an exposé? And should I think of expose as exactly the same as research proposal?

This is in the humanities.

Comment: I'm not sure that we can tell you, as different fellowships will have different expectations.

Comment: An A4 page (one side), any more and it is an article, paper or thesis...